# How to Make an XSL Row Invisible?

Tags: xml, vb.net, xslt, xpath

We have following XSL row

```
<w:tr wsp:rsidR="00EC796A" wsp:rsidRPr="00E83E5E" wsp:rsidTr="00CA49A2">
    <w:tc>
        <w:p wsp:rsidR="00EC796A" wsp:rsidRPr="00E83E5E" wsp:rsidRDefault="007D26AB" wsp:rsidP="00CA49A2">
            <w:r wsp:rsidRPr="00E83E5E">
                <w:t>
                    <xsl:text>EXPORT PRODUCTS</xsl:text>
                </w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ns0:Export_Products" />
    </w:tc>
</w:tr>
```

But if Export Products is null or count is 0, I want to make this row's visibility false. How can I achieve this?
By the way the template is like following if needed:

```
<xsl:template match="/ns0:ReportWordData/ns0:Export_Report/ns0:Export_Products">
    <ns0:Export_Products>
      <xsl:for-each select="@ns0:*|@*[namespace-uri()='']">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ns0:Product" />
    </ns0:Export_Products>
</xsl:template>
```

**Code behind:**

```
Dim myXslTransform As New XslCompiledTransform(False)
myXslTransform.Load(GetType(TemplateForExport))
myXslTransform.Transform(xmlFilePath, wordFilePath)
```

So making it invisible should be at runtime I think. Or there can be another solution.

Normally the word file is like this:

[image]

And we like these rows to not appear if they have no value.

Actually we can achieve this with changing templates but this way we have to create thousands of templates as there are many possibilities.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want the output to look like when the row has been set to be invisible. It looks like you are actually outputting WordprocessingML here, so strictly speaking it is not an "XSL Row" but a row in a Word 2003 XML Document. Thanks!

Comment: @TimC I edited the question but I'm not sure if it is what you wanted as I'm not very familiar to XSLT...

Comment: Before you write any XSLT you have to know what you want to the output to look like. In your case you are outputting XML used by Word. Imagine you were using Notepad to manually create the XML. What would that XML look like? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `xsl:if`, e.g.

```
<xsl:if test="ns0:Product">
    <xsl:text>EXPORT PRODUCTS</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
```